# How to display one row when table has multiple rows related to Single record in other table?

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86e60/1

I have data as below:

[image]

and trying to generate output as below:

[image]

Is there are any function in SQL to solve this kind of use case? I am not looking for complete answer. I am just looking for what to search for or Any pointers on how to solve this would be great.

**NOTE**: I have looked at similar posts but could not find anything close to this.

Comment: It looks like to want to [PIVOT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html).

Comment: HOW to pivot will depend on your Oracle version. Up to 10.2 you will need to pivot using conditional aggregation; from 11.1 you can use the `PIVOT` operator.

Comment: Why downvote? What is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pivot` version would be:

```
select * from (
   select apartment_id, feature_name, feature_value
   from   apartment_feature
)
pivot (
   max(feature_value)
   for feature_name in
       ( 'BedRooms' as bedrooms, 'BathRooms' as bathrooms, 'Flooring' as flooring )
)
order by apartment_id;
```

The `max(feature_value)` is because `pivot` syntax requires an aggregate expression here. Perhaps if `feature_value` were a numeric column then `sum(feature_value)` would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your time. This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select apartment_id,
       max(case when feature_name = 'bedrooms' then feature_value end) as bedrooms,
       max(case when feature_name = 'bathrooms' then feature_value end) as bathrooms,
       max(case when feature_name = 'flooring' then feature_value end) as flooring
from t
group by apartment_id;
```